# Not to drop database or tables with EF4.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-migrations

Is there a way to make Entity Framework 4.1 Code First NOT to drop database or the tables, not even if its changed? Im suppose to upgrade a LIVE site and I cant because of this. I seen some NuGet classes I can get but its to not drop database but tables, recreate tables on change ect.. i just do not want to do anything to the database or the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the startup of your application add this:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(null);
```

This should remove any initialization strategy.

Comment: This is out the box or i need to do a custom class for it? I place this in the global file?

Comment: Place it to `Application_Start` in your global.asax file.

Comment: Im just surprised how i missed this in the documentation. thanks